# WebExtension (Firefox) and access to JQuery

Tags: jquery, content-security-policy, firefox-addon-webextensions

I try to create a WebExtension which uses JQuery besides other scripts.

For testing I have modified the "Cookie BG Picker" extension here: https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/cookie-bg-picker

I modified two files manifest.json and bgpicker.html

In manifest.json in the head section I added

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://ajax.googleapis.com">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>console.log('Hello');</script>
<script>alert('Hello');</script>
```

and in manifest.json I added at end and:

```json
, "content_security_policy": "default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://ajax.googleapis.com"
```

Result: errors:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js (“script-src moz-extension://328f70d3-087f-46a2-a254-04c48b5a2e88”).  (unknown)
13:17:00.676 Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src moz-extension://328f70d3-087f-46a2-a254-04c48b5a2e88”).  bgpicker.html:12
13:17:00.676 Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src moz-extension://328f70d3-087f-46a2-a254-04c48b5a2e88”).
```

Some ideas, what I should change to avoid the errors?

Best

---

**Edit: Finally I got a solution. I created a short excerpt of the extension:**

1. manifest.json

```js
{
  "description": "Create a new window, gather data in that window, update a Github file",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Github-File-Update",
  "version": "1.0",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/...",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/page-48.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/page-32.png"
  },
  "permission": "<all_urls>",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://api.github.com; object-src 'self'; img-src 'self'"
}
```

2. background.js

```js
function onCreated(windowInfo) {
  console.log("Created window: " + windowInfo.id);
}
function onError(error) {
  console.log("Error: "+ error);
}
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  var popupURL = browser.extension.getURL(" github-extension-window.html");
  var creating = browser.windows.create({
    url: popupURL,
    type: "popup",
    height: 800,
    width: 600
  });
  creating.then(onCreated, onError);
});
```

3. github-extension-window.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Language' content='de-DE' />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="github-extension-window.css"/>

    <script src="jquery.3.1.1.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <h1 id="page-script-para">Github Extension Window</h1>

    <div>Code ...
    </div>

    <script src="github-extension-window.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

4. github-extension-window.css

```css
body {padding: 25px; height: 100%; background: #eee}
```

5. github-extension-window.js

```js
function doit() {

    function b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
        return decodeURIComponent(Array.prototype.map.call(atob(str), function (c) {
            return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }).join(''));
    };

    function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
        return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function (match, p1) {
            return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
        }));
    };

    var accessToken = ' ... ';

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.github.com/repos/ ... json?ref=gh-pages",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log('...');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log('ERROR GET CONTENT: ' + JSON.stringify(error, null, '\t'));
        }
    });


    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.github.com/repos/ ... json?ref=gh-pages",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            setSHA(data.data.sha);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log('ERROR GET OLD SHA: ' + JSON.stringify(error, null, '\t'));
        }
    });

    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    var contentBase64 = b64EncodeUnicode('[{"1a": "111a","2a": "222a"}]'); // TEST DATA
    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    function setSHA(sha) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.github.com/repos/ ... json?access_token=" + accessToken,
            type: "PUT",
            data: '{"message":"update from api","committer":{"name":"...","email":"..."},"content":"' + contentBase64 + '","sha":"' + sha + '","branch":"gh-pages"}',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('RESULT: ' + JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'));
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log('ERROR PUT: ' + JSON.stringify(error, null, '\t'));
            }
        });

    }
}

doit();
```

Hope, it can help!

Comment: Probably down to your Content Security tag have you tried adding `data: gap:` into your security tag. His the one i used when using googleapis  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: * https://*.google.com  https://*.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />`

Comment: No, it's as I said, I only added the lines mentioned above. In the meantime I removed the modification in manifest.json after trying your code, but it's not difference: errors.

Comment: ok here is a link [https://content-security-policy.com ] to the content security tag might be some thing to do with loading external scripts

Comment: I've been there before, my browser is supported. I've been also at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP and https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/web-extension-cannot-load-jquery-into-background-page-due-to-csp/10239

Comment: are you loading external scripts?... do you need for them to be external?... can you not add them to your local file system. See if this makes any difference. As the error points to loading an external script and that it has been blocked by the security tag.

Comment: I had it locally but it was no difference. And the errors apply to internal scripts, too.

Comment: As I just read, inline script code is not supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy Remains the jquery thing.

Comment: Did you really do what you say: "In manifest.json in the head"? Did you really put HTML in your *manifest.json*, or did you mean some HTML file?

Comment: The answer is NOT "Error: Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource"!